# Android Studio DownloadManager deletes File after download

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

I download Files with the DownloadManager and actually these files are deleted after downloading.
My search didn't get any results (as far as I can see) so I hope to get some help here.

```
DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://mysite/file");
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(PDFActivity.this, "/Download/", "file.pdf");
            downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
            registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(downloadmanager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
```

```
BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete=new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            unregisterReceiver(onDownloadComplete);
        }
}
```

This is the short version of my code.
Can anyobdy explain what's the problem and give me some advice?

Greetings,
Chris

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is used for questions/issues with the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: How are you checking if the file is in the specified directory? With your app? We do not believe that the file gets deleted.

Comment: Also tell full path if directory used and directory checked.